# Return One single row as result from multiple Sub-Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Query which gets all odds at a particular time of a particular match from multiple bookies. I would like to return a single row for each match with all the relevant information.

Current Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT  f.fixtureDate,
        (SELECT team FROM bet.team WHERE teamId = homeTeam),
        (SELECT team FROM bet.team WHERE teamId = awayTeam),
        (SELECT oddValue WHERE bookieID = '5D9130BD-00E6-4D72-BFC5-01DA15CA4CE8' AND direction = '599065F7-96A9-4DF5-8577-2203BE9AA2E0') AS 'company1H',
        (SELECT oddValue WHERE bookieID = '5D9130BD-00E6-4D72-BFC5-01DA15CA4CE8' AND direction = '5C27D6EF-DC8E-4A82-B18C-3139E3884691') AS 'company1D',
        (SELECT oddValue WHERE bookieID = '5D9130BD-00E6-4D72-BFC5-01DA15CA4CE8' AND direction = 'ABD92DB9-58D8-4C60-8A34-4C00EBBAB4A5') AS 'company1A'
FROM bet.betEntry be JOIN bet.fixture f ON be.fixtureId = f.fixtureId 
WHERE fixtureDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, '2018/12/08 16:00',120) and lastUpdated = CONVERT(VARCHAR, '2018/12/08 16:00',120)
```

Current Output :

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         Date        |     Home Team    |      Away Team      |     company1H    |      company1D      |     company1A    |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    08/12/18 16:00   |      Arsenal     |     HuddersField    |       1.55       |         NULL        |       NULL       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    08/12/18 16:00   |      Arsenal     |     HuddersField    |       NULL       |         2.10        |       NULL       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    08/12/18 16:00   |      Arsenal     |     HuddersField    |       NULL       |         NULL        |       5.20       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

How can I combine the outputs in such a way that the output looks like example below

Desired Output :

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         Date        |     Home Team    |      Away Team      |     company1H    |      company1D      |     company1A    |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    08/12/18 16:00   |      Arsenal     |     HuddersField    |       1.55       |         2.10        |       5.20       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @D-Shih MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You want conditional aggregation.  I think this is the query:

```
SELECT f.fixtureDate, th.team, ta.team,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bookieID = '5D9130BD-00E6-4D72-BFC5-01DA15CA4CE8' AND direction = '599065F7-96A9-4DF5-8577-2203BE9AA2E0'
                THEN oddValue
           END) AS company1H,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bookieID = '5D9130BD-00E6-4D72-BFC5-01DA15CA4CE8' AND direction = '5C27D6EF-DC8E-4A82-B18C-3139E3884691'
                THEN oddValue
           END) AS company1D,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bookieID = '5D9130BD-00E6-4D72-BFC5-01DA15CA4CE8' AND direction = 'ABD92DB9-58D8-4C60-8A34-4C00EBBAB4A5'
                THEN oddValue
           END) AS company1A
FROM bet.betEntry be JOIN
     bet.fixture f
     ON be.fixtureId = f.fixtureId LEFT JOIN
     bet.team th
     ON ?.teamId = th.homeTeam LEFT JOIN
     bet.team ta
     ON ?.teamId = ta.awayTeam
WHERE ?.fixtureDate = '2018-12-08 16:00' AND
      ?.lastUpdated = '2018-12-08 16:00'
GROUP BY f.fixtureDate, th.team, ta.team;
```

Notes:

- I don't understand why you are converting a string to a string using a date format, to compare to a date.  Seems really complicated.
- You should qualify all column names. I've put `?.` in the query to identify where they are needed.
- Conditional aggregation should be doing what you want.